# Error while browsing WCF service

Tags: wcf, config

> 2009-11-03 16:36:10,818 [3404] ERROR WebApplication.Global [UserHostAddress: [::1] ApplicationSource [//TestService.svc]] - Application_Error handled Exception: Stack trace for 1 exception(s). Root cause at the top.
>   1: An item with the same key has already been added.
>      System.ArgumentException
>      inside C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll
>      at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Can you post the code/config file?  What do you mean by 'browsing'?

Answer (score 3):

This was happening for me because:
1. My IIS web application's advanced settings indicated "http,https" in "Enabled Protocols".
2. The "Default Web Site"'s "Site Bindings" did not have an https binding type.

And in order to resolve the issue, I had to do **one** of the following:
1. Remove "https" from the "Enabled Protocols" of my IIS web application's advanced settings.
2. Add the "https" binding type to the "Default Web Site"'s "Site Bindings".

Comment: Thank you Rami, this was it for me. Hopefully this helps others too. I threw in https in the Enabled Protocols to match staging and production, but of course, my dev environment doesn't have SSL enabled. Very tough one to track down, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config file. You probably have two entries that have the same name, same contract, or some other duplication.