# WCF - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis, binding

I keep getting an error when trying to open WCF WebService via http://www.example.com/WS/myExchange.svc:

> System.ArgumentException
>   An item with the same key has already been added.
>
> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been
>   added.    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar)

When I open the same WS on the localhost, everything works normally.

I don't even know where to start searching for the root of the problem.

Is the problem in IIS configuration, installed modules, project code?

How to find out which item with the same key has already been added? Even if is it in Web.Config? In code? In database? In included modules?

Problem appears only on "/WS/myExchange.svc", other parts of the website work normally.

Advanced settings:
[image]

Site bindings:
[image]

Comment: Why downwote? Thx for explanation...

Comment: Sorry, can't read bindings from image, can you post text instead, thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

In Web.Config, section system.serviceModel I had to add:

```
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Answer (score 11):

A possible cause is

1. Your IIS web application's advanced settings indicates "http,https" in "Enabled Protocols".
2. The "Default Web Site"'s "Site Bindings" does not have an https binding type.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19440427/6996876

Comment: (I updated question with printscreens) Unfortunately neither of your suggestions doesn't seem to be the cause :/

Answer (score 0):

Check:

> 1. Web.Config elements it could be possible duplicate.
> 2. Check also whether it is 32 or 64 bit application in IIS.
> 3. Application pools framework.

Comment: There's no duplicates in Web.Config (since both, local and production host use the same Web.Configs, and it works on the local). Application in IIS is strictly 64-bit, the same on the local. What do you mean by application pools framework?

Comment: @Tadej You can choose between 2.0 and 4.0 .Net frameworks when configuring an application pool on IIS. The optional 2.0 .NET framework covers up to version 3.5 as well. The 4.0 covers up to the latest installed version on the server which is currently 4.7.3. .Net 5.0 is close to release this may add a third option. The installed framework versions can be selected in the installed Roles portion of the Server Manager or downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

2023-12-08 I had this same exact error with IIS10 after renewing my certificates for one of my websites.

It was the first time I had this problem over at least 20 certificate renew process I've done so far.

Here was the solution to my problem:

Deleted all the https bindings of my website and remade them exactly identical.